# Horizontal scroll offsets inner divs depending on how many lines text are in them

Tags: css

I'm presenting multiply cards in a horizontal scroll. Each card has a title that's cut off if the text is longer than two lines.

To get the horizontal scroll im using `white-space: nowrap` and `overflow-x: auto`.
For the text to cut off I need to set `white-space: normal` for getting the effect.

But now each card gets offset depending on how long the title is (one or two lines).

My code:

```
.list {
  padding-left: 36px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 310px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

...

```
.card--title {
  margin: 0;
  white-space: normal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The result:
[Image of the List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P36TO.png)

Any fix for the offset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix: Use `display: flex` on list instead of `display: inline-block` on card:

Code:

```
.list {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 24px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.card {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 310px;
}
```